# C++ macro similar to __LINE__ but to find position in the given line?

Tags: c++, macros

So, what I am interested in is a macro that would be similar to `__LINE__`, but instead of returning the line number, it could return the position within the given line.

It could be the position in the line both in terms of columns or of chars. For instance, in the code:

```
#define THISCHAR
int main(void)
{
    THISCHAR
}
```

The macro `CHAR` should return either 5, because it is in the position of character 5 of its line, or maybe return 1, because it is the first non-empty char of the line. Either option could work for me.

Is such a thing possible to achieve during compile time?

Comment: No. This is not supported in any compiler I am aware of because whitespace is stripped during tokenization. Second, because of token substitution in the preprocessor, it would be difficult to tell if a given location in a line (after a function call or whatnot) was after a macro and would involve another pass of the preprocessor.

Answer (score 3):

C++20 now has `std::source_location`, which has a column function.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location/column

Answer (score 2):

Not to my knowledge, no. While some are defined by C99 standard, the rest of these macros are specific to your compiler and AFAIK are not defined by the language itself.

If you are using Visual Studio, here is a list of the predefined macros:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx 
The ones that are standard there as well.

I do wonder what you would use such a macro for. For

```
__LINE__
```

it is often to mark the expression where an error occurred, for use as a field in an exception for example. I can't fathom a use for column, since things are evaluated as statements and expressions, not one character at a time.

Answer (score 0):

User [@scx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71613923/4506399) regarding `std::source_location` seems to work for your case if I understand correctly. You can use `constexpr` so it is during compile time, and it works even if you call the function from a different file. For anyone not familiar with it, here are some sample functions.

**Note**: By default, the line column/position will be at the end of the function name before parentheses "()".

**Get line column/position of *end* of function name call**

```
#include <source_location>

constexpr uint_least32_t getLineColumn(
    const std::source_location &location = std::source_location::current())
{
    return location.column();
}
```

The following test code will yield "29", the end of `getLineColumn`.

```
// Yields "29" here -----><-----
int column = getLineColumn();
```

If you want the line column/position to be at the beginning  of the function call, then you will need to do some math to subtract the length of the function name to get that position.

**Get line column/position of *beginning* of function name call**

```
#include <source_location>

constexpr uint_least32_t getLineColumnBegin(
    const std::source_location &location = std::source_location::current())
{
    return location.column() - 18; // "getLineColumnBegin" has length "18". Change this value if you change the function name.
}
```

The following test code will yield "23", the beginning of `getLineColumnBegin`.

```
// Yields "23" --><-- here
int columnBegin = getLineColumnBegin();
```

**If you want to handle any function name length, you can use `#define` and then `std::string` `length()`**

```
#include <source_location>

#define GET_FUNCTION_NAME(function) (#function)

constexpr uint_least32_t getLineColumnBegin(
    const std::source_location &location = std::source_location::current())
{
    return location.column() - std::string(GET_FUNCTION_NAME(getLineColumnBegin)).length();
}
```

The following test code will yield "23", the beginning of `getLineColumnBegin`.

```
// Yields "23" --><-- here
int columnBegin = getLineColumnBegin();
```